# Why can't set the wireless access point in my debian?

Tags: wifi, dnsmasq, hostapd, access-point

My wireless adapter:

```
lsusb | rg -i  wireless
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

List my network interface:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx38a28c80c24f  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Install hostapd and set up configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
sudo vim  /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlx38a28c80c24f
driver=nl80211
ssid=myap
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT40-][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=linuxprobe
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Install dnsmasq and set up configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
sudo vim /etc/dnsmasq.conf
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
server=/cn/114.114.114.114
server=/taobao.com/114.114.114.114
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.11.1
dhcp-range=192.168.11.50,192.168.11.150,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.11.1
dhcp-option=6,192.168.11.1
cache-size=1024
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d

sudo vim /etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
nameserver 114.114.114.114

sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Start the services:

```
sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service
sudo systemctl start hostapd.service
```

Now connect `myap` with password `linuxprobe`,why the access point can't be accessed via my android phone?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git
cd create_ap
sudo make install
ifconfig
    enp6s0
    wlx38a28c80c24f
sudo ifconfig wlx38a28c80c24f up 
wlan="wlx38a28c80c24f"
eth="enp6s0"
create_ap $wlan $eth MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
sudo systemctl start create_ap
```

Now i can connect the AP setting by create_ap from android phone.

Comment: Note that the `create_ap` Github repository is _archived_ and that the author is suggesting using other similar projects.